# Closed unit ball in $\ell^p$ is compact

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, compactness

I'm curious as to whether the closed unit ball in $\ell^p$ is compact for $1 \leq p \leq \infty$, with respect to the $p$-norm, and the $\sup$ norm?

Comment: In which topology?

Comment: I haven't taken a course in topology, only in metric spaces. I'm not sure how to answer your question.

Comment: So I assume you are referring to the notion of sequential compactness: That a set is compact if every sequence has a convergent subsequence. In this case you can check that when $1\le p\le \infty$, $\ell^p$ are noncompact. (Try to think of a sequence)

Comment: http://planetmath.org/compactnessofclosedunitballinnormedspaces

Comment: So since $\ell^p$ is not finite dimensional $\forall p \geq 1$, the closed ball is not compact in $\ell^p$?

Comment: @Jordan It really depends on the topology you consider. In the weak-* topology (when we consider $\ell^p$ as a dual space) it will be compact. When we consider if with it's usual norm topology is will not be compact, since unit balls in normed vector spaces are compact iff the space is finite dimensional